# When creating an <input> element, onchange after adding is not part of it

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, appendchild

I added some elements to my table. There is a function to add (tr and td) those elements. Inside the function there is a part:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    cell = document.createElement("td");
    row.appendChild(cell);
    cellData = document.createElement("input");
    cellData.type = "number";
    cellData.min = "0"
    cellData.max = "7";
    cellData.value = "0";
    cellData.onchange = "calculate()";
    cell.appendChild(cellData);
}
```

This puts 4 cells with input field. My problem is, that the onchange part doesn't work. I know u can add onchange function to an input directly. But in this form it doesn't work. I know that cause when i checked it in the browser it skipped the onchange part:

```
<td><input type="number" min="0" max="7"></td>
```

It only added these. And also i didn't get my message from a the function:

```
function calculate() {
    console.log("something");
}
```

Can somebody give me a solution for this problem? Thank u for your time and answer!

Comment: Try `cellData.addEventListener("change", calculate)`, or try setting the `onchange` attribute AFTER adding the cellData to the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better

```
cellData.onchange = calculate;
```

Even better

```
cellData.addEventListener("change",calculate);
```

Best since it only has ONE event listener:

```
document.querySelector("#myTable tbody").addEventListener("input",calculate);
```

Example

```js
const getNum = str => isNaN(str) || str.trim() === "" ? 0 : +str;

const tbody = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody");
const totalSpan = document.getElementById('total');
const calculate = fld => {
  const total = [...tbody.querySelectorAll("[type=number]")].map(fld => getNum(fld.value)).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
  totalSpan.textContent = total;
};

tbody.addEventListener("input", calculate);


const row = document.createElement("tr")
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  cell = document.createElement("td");
  cellData = document.createElement("input");
  cellData.type = "number";
  cellData.min = "0"
  cellData.max = "7";
  cellData.value = "0";
  cell.appendChild(cellData);
  row.appendChild(cell);
}
tbody.appendChild(row);
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: this is better solution

Comment: See example I just added

Answer (score 0):

```js
var row = window.document.createElement('tr');
document.getElementById("content").appendChild(row);
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    cell = document.createElement("td");
    row.appendChild(cell);
    cellData = document.createElement("input");
    cellData.type = "number";
    cellData.min = "0"
    cellData.max = "7";
    cellData.value = "0";
    cellData.onchange = calculate ;
    cell.appendChild(cellData);
    
}
function calculate() {
    console.log("something");
}
```

```html
<div id="content"> </div>
```

Comment: yes i guess, but the op didn't ask for that